# Multi Level Header Issues

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am trying to create a multi-level header component and I am running into an issue. Some of the columns don't have a second or third level, but I want them to fill the space vertically and cannot seem to find a way to do this. Does anyone have any insight or links to documentation that can point me in the right direction? Code below is the ColDefs for the fields that only need to be a single level. Every other field is 2-3 levels deep. Adding a picture as well.

```
{
    field: 'he',
    width: 50,
    headerComponentParams: {
      displayName: 'HE',
      autoHeaderHeight: false,
    },
    cellClass: 'vAlign'
  },
  {
    field: 'loadForecast',
    width: 150,
    headerComponentParams: {
      displayName: 'Gross Load Forecast(kW) / Gross Load Actual (kW)',
    },
  },
```

How it looks now:
[image]

How I need it to look:
[image]

And here is a list of my columns:

[image]

Comment: Please read [ask], especially the section titled "Write a title that summarizes the problem"; note how it talks about not using tags in titles. Also, pictures of code are rarely as useful as the code they picture - after all, if someone wanted to recreate the issue, they can hardly paste the image into their IDE.

Comment: Updated the title. I am not asking for anyone to reproduce code. I asked for guidance on where to look to find out how to style the column headers. Not help with my code specifically

Comment: @HereticMonkey not using tags in title is a stupid advise here because this question is for a very specific lib. currently it is hard to understand just by reading the title or text.

Comment: @Welcor Comments are not the place to discuss guidelines. [meta] is. Note that it is a simple matter of looking at the tags to see what library is being used. You are also free to [edit] the question to incorporate the tag name fluidly into the title. For instance, a title that better summarizes the problem being asked would be great, rather than simply "Multiple Header Issues" which tells you nothing except that the OP has some kind of issue with multiple headers. Even "Multiple Header Issues using AG-Grid", which would not fall afoul of the prohibition on tags in titles, would not help.

Comment: its a matter of using colspan and rowspan properties for the td or th tags in the html template

Comment: @OmarAbdullwahhab this is for AG-Grid, not standard html tags